# How to make RaphaelJS vertical align text for both Chrome / Firefox vs IE 7 and 8?

Tags: svg, raphael, vml

I thought RaphaelJS is supposed to be the same when it is Chrome / Firefox and in IE 7 and 8?

The example at

http://jsfiddle.net/8UPhS/1/

The text is vertically centered on Chrome and Firefox, but on IE 7 and 8, the baseline of the text is centered instead (so it is several pixels higher than in FF)...  Is there a way to make them all behave the same?

(preferably not to use browser detection and adjust the text a few pixels lower for IE 7 and 8, as it is not such a clean solution)

(on IE 9, for some reason the image is not showing at all, even if using Developer Tool to change Compat mode to IE 7 or 8... but if I do it on IE 9 using a separate page linking the `raphael.js` on the same website of `index.html`, then I get the worst situation of all: sometimes I get one behavior, sometimes I get the other behavior, at random... it almost looks like it is a race condition)

(for IE 9, this page can be used:

http://try-raphael-text.heroku.com
http://try-raphael-text.heroku.com/raphael20.html

the second link is using Raphael 2.0 on GitHub's Raphael 2.0 branch

the 2.0 version actually works on IE 7 to vertical align, but on IE 8, no text is shown...
it works well on IE 9 using this simple case... but on our real page, it is able to crash IE 9 sometimes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug in Raphael 1.5.2 [1]. I would prefer feature-detection over browser-detection to workaround this bug? Raphael provides a property called svg (true|false). Look at my example: http://jsbin.com/iwudu5/edit.

[1] https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/86

Comment: so you are saying that, if svg, then do nothing, but if not svg (then it must be VML), then add 3 pixels to the vertical?

Comment: yes, exactly. "3px" is just a placeholder because this code snippet has never been tested on IE (VML).